# jqGrid 4.2 Custom search with non-grid fields

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.2 with the `filterToolbar`, which works great. I'd like to add some type of custom search to query (server-side) fields that are not part of the `colModel`.

Prior to 4.0 I would have used `filterGrid` along the lines of this:

```js
$('#keyword').jqGrid('filterGrid', '#ticket-grid',
    {
       gridModel: false, 
       filterModel: [
            { label: 'Keyword', name: 'keyword', stype: 'text'},
            { label: 'Inclued Closed?',name : 'includeClosed', stype: 'checkbox'}
       ]
     });
```

I understand that this is no longer supported, and an `stype: 'checkbox'` doesn't work anyway.

How do I do this with the new search module/mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct you have already on the page, for example above the grid, some controls (text input, selects, chechboxes) which allow the user to define additional criteria of the results which the user want see in the grid. In the case you can use `postData` with methods (functions) in the way described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935).

If any kind of grid refreshing: request to filter the data from the [searching toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching), changing of the page or the page size, changing of sorting and so on will always follow to the Ajax request to the server. In the case the properties from `postData` option of jqGrid will be added like other standard parameters (`sidx`, `sord`, `page`, ...). If one from the properties of the `postData` is defined as function (if a method of `postData`) then the function will be called to construct the parameter which will be sent to the server. So the current information from you custom searching controls (text input, selects, chechboxes) will be send to the server. In the way you need only use the parameters on the backend to filter the results.

So you have to define fields yourself. For example the text input with id="keyword-input" and checkbos with id="includeClosed" and then use `postData` in about the following form:

```js
$('#keyword').jqGrid(
    // ... other jqGrid options
    postData: {
        keyword: function () { return $('#keyword-input').val(); },
        includeClosed: function () { return $('#includeClosed')is(':checked'); },
    }
});
```

Comment: This is great and far less complicated than I was trying to make it. Thank you.

Comment: to add keyword and includeclosed to postData filters property ? In this case no additional parameters are required to pass server.

Comment: @Andrus: `keyword` and `includeclosed` and not parts of the standard filter. There are parts of external fields which are not part of the grid. See the title of the question: "Custom search with non-grid fields".

Comment: I asked about extending filters property which is passed to server like `.. and keyword=$('#keyword-input').val() and includeClosed=$('#includeClosed')is(':checked')` server can construct where clause without additional parameters needed

Comment: @Andrus: Sorry, I still can't follow you. Is your question about my answer or it's new question about some other situation which you has? The property `filters` of `postData` will be constructed by jqGrid as string (serialized object) and can contain only field from the grid. So if you open searching dialog the filters will be decoded and will be filled in the searching dialog. I don't understand what you want and which relation has it to my answer.

Comment: This was proposal to you answer to extend filters parameter passed to server so that it contains search condition for additional columns also.